# How to correctly re-connect to Socket-IO server with params

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, chat

I'm creating some king of chat. User must be authenticated to join room. On my backend server, I've created login middleware:

```
io.use((socket, next) => {
    try {
        const token = encodeURIComponent(socket.handshake.auth.token);
        const user = encodeURIComponent(socket.handshake.auth.user);
        
        if (token.length < 100) {
            next(new Error("Forbidden"));
        }

        const decoded = jwt.verify(socket.handshake.auth.token, SECRET_KEY);

        socket.user = user;
        socket.userId = decoded._id;
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        next(new Error("Forbidden"));
    }
})
```

It's checking `auth` prop to get encrypted JWT token. Once auth completed, `next()` is called.
On my front-end I'm using `createContext` to create "storage" for my websocket connection and `SocketProvider` to use websocket along my pages.

```
export const SocketProvider = ({ children }: { children: JSX.Element } ) => {
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState<SocketIOClient>(null);
  const token = window.localStorage.getItem("token");
  const user = window.localStorage.getItem("user");

  useEffect(() => {
    const newSocket = io(BACKEND_URL, {
      auth: {
          token: token,
          user: user
      }
    });
    setSocket(newSocket);

    return () => {
      newSocket.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <SocketIOContext.Provider value={ socket }>
      { children }
    </SocketIOContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Websocket connection is null after logining. I've checked this by using `console.log()`. This is happening because `useEffect` connection to websocket with no token, so back-end server sending "Forbidden", then `socket === null`.

My question is: how can I force React reconnect to websocket when `children` is changing or when token isn't null?

Answer (score 1):

I got it. You have to pass token to redux storage, then in `useEffect` add dependency with this var. When token is changinx in redux, then socket is re-connecting to server with auth-token, as expected.